looking for help on changing line attributes of single horizontal lines in wxgrid.lua
I'm programming a wx.grid application under lua. I want to change the width and colour of some single horizontal lines.
I was looking for a function (method) like 'grid.wx.SetRowGridLineWidth(columnnumber,custom_width)', or 'grid.wx.SetRowGridLineColour(columnnumber,custom_wx.colour)'. Indeed such basic and elementary functions seem not to exist.
I found some workaround based on 'grid.wx.GetRowGridLinePen(self, columnnumber)'. For that I would have to override this virtual function or derive a class.
Unfortunately I have no idea at all how to derive a class, or how to override a function. I found an example using python, but I did not succeed in transferring it to lua and getting it to work. You see, I'm not an advanced programmer, but nevertheless I think that there ought to be a user-friendly solution to such a basic problem.
